# Automate some Exchange Online functions

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

Having that Exchange Online functions are not yet included in MS Graph, and Exchange does not have its own SDK also, the only option I found to automate some functions in Exchange Online is `ExchangeOnlineManagement` PowerShell.

I used it for a while but Microsoft recently ceased the Basic Authentication. I'm using the Basic Authentication because it does not require any prior package installation.

The modern authentication use `Connect-ExchangeOnline` and requires the `ExchangeOnlineManagement` to be installed prior to any call. It's easy to install it on a physical server or a VM, but I'm relying on Azure services, like azure Web app, azure Function app, where I cannot install a package. now the situation is:

1. Basic authentication stopped working, and it's not an option
   anymore. This was the only option to execute exchange PowerShell
   commands from azure web app or function app.
2. In modern authentication, you rely on the ExchangeOnlineManagement
   that must be installed prior to any call. since I work on web app, or function
   app, I cannot install it.
3. there is no .net Exchange SDK.
4. MS Graph lack Exchange functions.

So what is the valid solution to execute Exchange command? Maybe the solution is available but I'm not aware of it.

My case is simple: Every night, Upon the expiration of an Azure user account:

- I change some user properties on Azure (Available through MS Graph)
- I need to set an auto reply message, so sender can know the email
  account is no longer monitored. (**NOT AVAILABLE**)

Comment: looks like its available on the beta version of the api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell

Comment: I'm talking about the exchange management functions, and not user function. for example, hide a mailbox from address list, convert to shared mailbox, set automatic reply... the functions that you can do it usually, when you login as admin to the exchange admin portal, and not what a user can do in his own mailbox

Comment: Did you look into azure runbook from azure automation? You can install dependencies and execute ps5 or ps7 script without vm. You can also trigger the runbook through webhook or via schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true in the connection string and if for example you currently have user creds being passed in switch to using the ROPC flow with those creds and just pass the username and accesstoken where you passing the users password eg

```html
PSCredential pSCredential = new PSCredential("user@blah.onmicrosoft.com", new NetworkCredential("", "pass##").SecurePassword);
string MailboxName = pSCredential.UserName;
string scope = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default";
string ClientId = "a0c73c16-a7e3-4564-9a95-2bdf47383716";

HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
var TenantId = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Client.GetAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + MailboxName.Split('@')[1] + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)).authorization_endpoint.ToString().Split('/')[3];

PublicClientApplicationBuilder pcaConfig = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId);
pcaConfig.WithTenantId(TenantId);
var TokenResult = pcaConfig.Build().AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(new[] { scope }, pSCredential.UserName, pSCredential.Password).ExecuteAsync().Result;

System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();

foreach (char c in ("bearer " + TokenResult.AccessToken))
    secureString.AppendChar(c);
String WSManURIConnectionString = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?DelegatedOrg=" + MailboxName.Split('@')[1] + "&BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true";
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(MailboxName, secureString);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(WSManURIConnectionString), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4;
Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
// Make a Get-Mailbox requst using the Server Argument
Command gmGetMailbox = new Command("get-mailbox");
gmGetMailbox.Parameters.Add("ResultSize", "Unlimited");
Pipeline plPileLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
plPileLine.Commands.Add(gmGetMailbox);
Collection<PSObject> RsResultsresults = plPileLine.Invoke();
Dictionary<string, PSObject> gmResults = new Dictionary<string, PSObject>();
foreach (PSObject obj in RsResultsresults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Members["WindowsEmailAddress"].Value.ToString());
}
Command gmGetUser = new Command("get-user");
plPileLine.Stop();
plPileLine.Dispose();
```